# Merge a single commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Let's say I've working on a branch `X`. The recent commit I made was `20 minutes` ago.
Now, I wanted to merge a commit from the organization's official repo, but that commit was changed some 20 days ago.

Is there any way by which I could merge that commit keeping the correct order of commits (by time) in my repo.

Currently, if I did `git cherry-pick <sha1>`, it merged the commit, but it became the `HEAD`.

**EDIT**

```
A1--A2--A3--A4--A5--A6--A7--HEAD ----master (official: `upstream`)

A1--A2--A4--A5--A6--A7--A8--A9--A10 ----mybranch (github repo : `origin`)

A1--A2--A4--A5--A6--A7--A8--A9--A10 ----mybranch (local repo on system)

My aim: Merge the upstream's `A3` commit **in its own place**:

A1--A2--**A3**--A4--A5--A6--A7--A8--A9--A10 ----mybranch (github repo : `origin`)

A1--A2--**A3**--A4--A5--A6--A7--A8--A9--A10 ----mybranch (local repo on system)

(NOT THIS):

A1--A2--A4--A5--A6--A7--A8--A9--A10--**A3**
```

Comment: side-note: cherry-pinking and merging are two **very** different things, don’t mix them up. Are `A4` on mybranch and `A4` on master really the same commit? And if yes, how did you get into this (messy) state at all?

Answer (score 0):

that is possible using `rebase` or more cherry-picking, but I am not gonna go into detail here, because you are probably trying something you shouldn’t. Why do you want to lie about your history and pretend that that commit was part of your branch at a point in time that it wasn’t?

You can simply merge and `git log --date-order` will give you your commits in correct date order :).

Comment: I'll give you the reason why I'm not doing anything wrong. I was working on making a plugin on separate branch. I made lots of commits, etc. Then, one day, I found a bug. I reported it and it took almost 3 weeks to get integrated in the official repo. (I couldn't simply wait for 3 weeks and stop coding). So, now when it has been (it's my own patch integrated into the official repo) integrated, I thought of merging it onto my work.

Comment: @ptokya: Perhaps you should have illustrated that in the original question :-)

Comment: @torek: I never thought of someone accusing me. ;) <please help. i'm lost. or post a link to tutorial/blog/post>

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to another answer, you're saying that the development looks something like this:

```
C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- F2 --- C5       <-- master, origin/master (or similar)
   \
    W1 --- FX --- W2 --- W3 --- W4 --- W5  <-- workbranch
```

You wrote fix `FX` several weeks ago on your work branch, along with commits `W1` through `W5`.  They (whoever controls `origin/master` or `origin/feature` or whatever you're working on a branch-of) finally got around to committing it, perhaps with other commits (`C3` through `C5`) above.  Because it's a different commit (even though it makes the same change), I've labeled it `F2`.

You *can* rebase your branch on top of `F2` but that will necessarily get you the changes from `C3` and `C4` at the least, and `C5` if you want it too.  If that's what you want, just do:

```
$ git rebase -i master
```

while you are on your `workbranch`.  Since your fix `FX` is already included (although now called `F2`), delete it (a `pick` line in the file you're editing when you start the rebase) from the list of changes you want carried over, then let the interactive rebase run.  Of course you'll also want to make sure that each of your commits `W1` through `W5` still work on their own, now that they're based on a different commit (`C5`, above).  If not you may need to do another `rebase -i` and fix up each commit as needed.  And, the rebase may run into conflicts, which you will have to resolve manually.  But assuming all this works, you'll end up with this:

```
C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- F2 --- C5       <-- master, origin/master (or similar)
                              \
                               W1' --- W2' ... --- W5'  <-- workbranch
```

(The single quote `'` marks, borrowed from math notation, indicate that these are *new* commits that merely "do the same thing" as the commits `W1`, `W2`, etc.  This is what `rebase` does: it takes an existing chain of commits, and makes a new chain of commits, starting elsewhere, that "do the same thing" as the old chain, then removes the label—`workbranch`, in this case—from the old chain and pastes it on the new one.)

If you're lucky, there *are* no "extra" commits (`C3` and `C4` above): your work-branch comes off commit C2, then the next one on your remote "main line" is your fix F2.  If commit `W1` works OK with the fix, you can do, e.g.:

```
$ git rebase -i <sha1-of-F2>
```

and again delete the `pick` line for your commit `FX`, since its contents are the same as `F2`.  In this case you will get a commit tree that looks like:

```
C2 --- F2 --- C5                     <-- master, origin/master (or similar)
          \
            W1' --- W2' --- W3' --- W4' --- W5'  <-- workbranch
```

In each case, the point here is the same: make a new chain of changes (your "W"ork), hung off a point in `origin/whatever` at or after "they" put your bug-fix commit `FX` in as commit `F2`.  The problem here is also the same: you tested your work when it branched off C2, and the new work-chain branches off some other commit, so maybe some or all of your work is now subtly broken.

Note: when you do rebase stuff, you can keep a label pasted on your original work, which will make it easy to get at the original series of commits (`W1`, `FX`, `W2`, ... above), by doing something like:

```
git branch original-workbranch workbranch
```

before you start any rebasing.  When you're happy that everything is fine in the "new" version, you can delete the extra label:

```
git branch -D original-workbranch
```

If you forget or don't bother with this "save" step and later want to recover the original work branch, it can be done after the fact (typically for about 90 days) via the "ref log" (see `git reflog --help`), but it's more work at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but guess this is not what I really want. Please see my edited question.

Comment: If `mybranch` (as in the edited question) is exposed to other people (as it would be on github) then yes, you don't want to rebase; but no, you can't make them go in "date order" without rebasing.  Just merge and be happy. :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, what if I really need to rebase? I tried to rebase, but it ran into some errors, due to which I has to reset `HEAD_ORIG`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not without creating new commits. That is, if your local commits from `A4` onwards were local-only, you could rebase; seeing as they're on origin, though, it will cause headaches.

If I understand correctly, this is the situation you're in, and you'd like to insert `G` between `B` and `C`.

```
* H (upstream/master)
* G
* F
| * E (master, origin/master)
| * D
| * C
|/
* B
* A
```

The crucial point is that commits are *defined* by their ancestry. That is, `C` is *defined* by the fact that `B` is its parent (this is also true for `F`). You can make a new commit on top of `B`, but to "insert a commit between `B` and `C`" means changing `C`'s parent, which means `C` isn't `C` anymore.

The history you're after is certainly possible (but this will cause problems):

```
git rebase --onto G B E
git checkout -B master HEAD   # The '-B' option isn't related to the commit 'B'.
```

What that rebase does is replay the range `B..E` on top of `G`, i.e. re-committing `C`, `D`, `E`'s patches in turn on top of `G`. You'd be in this state:

```
* H (upstream/master)
| * E' (master)
| * D'
| * C'
|/
* G
* F
| * E (origin/master)
| * D 
| * C
|/
* B
* A
```

`C'`, `D'`, `E'` are new commits representing the same changes in `C`, `D`, `E`, but they're not related to their original counterparts. Notice how master and origin/master have diverged now; to integrate them you'd have to merge them, and then you'd have `C`, `D`, `E`, duplicated as `C'`, `D'`, `E'` in your history.

To integrate `G` in this situation, the correct thing to do is merge it:

```
git merge G
```

That will pull in `G`, and `F` too, since it's an immutable part of `G`: commits are defined by their history. If you want to pull just `G`'s patch in, you have to cherry-pick it:

```
git cherry-pick G
```

However, just like a rebase, cherry-picking a commit creates a new commit using the original's patch, and so this will also cause commit duplication in your history. That's sometimes OK: occasionally you just need a certain commit right away (a hotfix for production, for example), and the duplication represents that. But in general it's not what you want, and merging is the way to go.